# How to add a column of data to the arraylist?

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to add a column of data called a (class) to the end of 2D array, means each value from the column must be added at end of each row. 
Example : suppose I have the following data contain 4 columns (A,B,C,D)and I need to add the column class{1.0,1.0,2.0,2.0,1.0,2.0} at the end

```
 A,    B,    C,    D,   class
 1.0, -1.0,  1.0,  1.0, 1.0
 0.0,  1.0,  0.0,  0.0, 1.0
 1.0,  0.0,  1.0,  1.0, 2.0
 1.0,  0.0, -1.0, -1.0, 2.0
 0.0,  1.0,  1.0,  1.0, 1.0
-1.0, -1.0,  0.0,  1.0, 2.0
```

But my code added the whole column at end of each row like this:

```
 1.0, -1.0,  1.0,  1.0, [1.0, 1.0, 2.0, 2.0, 1.0, 2.0]
 0.0,  1.0,  0.0,  0.0, [1.0, 1.0, 2.0, 2.0, 1.0, 2.0]
 1.0,  0.0,  1.0,  1.0, [1.0, 1.0, 2.0, 2.0, 1.0, 2.0]
 1.0,  0.0, -1.0, -1.0, [1.0, 1.0, 2.0, 2.0, 1.0, 2.0]
 0.0,  1.0,  1.0,  1.0, [1.0, 1.0, 2.0, 2.0, 1.0, 2.0]
-1.0, -1.0,  0.0,  1.0, [1.0, 1.0, 2.0, 2.0, 1.0, 2.0]
```

Here is the code

```
int datasetMat[][] = new int[numberofrows] [numberoffeatures];
double class[] = new double[numberofrows];
List<Double> list= new ArrayList<Double>();
List<String> array=  new ArrayList<String>();
BufferedReader br = null;
String line = "";
int countlines=0;
int filefeaturesnumbers=0;
br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename1));
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    String[] datalines = line.split(",");
    class[countlines]=Integer.parseInt(datalines[numberoffeatures-1]);
    filefeaturesnumbers = datalines.length;
    for (int df=0;df<datalines.length;df++){
        String datast = datalines[df];
        int dataint = Integer.parseInt(datast);
        datasetMat[countlines][df]=dataint;                
    }
    list.add(colclassVec[countlines]);
    countlines++;
}
Collections.addAll(array, list+"");
```

Comment: How did this code got compiled in first place? You cannot use keywords as variable names in Java.

Comment: Why do you need to use a separate array for the last column of data? It seems as though you are reading through all the data at the same time. Can't you just add the last value in each line the same way you are adding all the other values?

Comment: Thanks@MihirKekkar. The separate array for the last column of data is called class label in data mining. So I have to deal with the whole data firstly then add the class to data